# SQL query to fetch custom group by values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table having columns time, height and speed. I need to plot the values. But here I have a lot of values not possible to display in a screen. So, I want to group them with some condition like average speed for each X (Let say 100m) unit height, for different times.

How to write query for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT TIME, AVG(speed) AvgSpeed, ROUND(Height/100)*100 HeightLowerBorder
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY TIME, ROUND(Height/100)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but not giving exactly what it is expected. I use count(*) for different conditional values (tried with 100 and 1000), but both the cases, the count value returning the same.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not using count at all.

Comment: I use a surrounded select count to find no of rows, which must be change according to custom value

Comment: Oleg Dok you are correct but did a small mistake, yet your concept is exactly what is required. It need to convert integer value. Finally I modify it as

    SELECT TIME, AVG(speed) AvgSpeed, ROUND(Height/100)*100 HeightLowerBorder
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY TIME, ROUND(Height/100)*100

Comment: Understood. What is in your time column?